# Are legends on topic here,seeing its close ties in definition to folklore?

Tags: discussion

I am new to this site and would like to have some clarity for myself. I am not talking about urban legends either. Do you consider folklore and legend to be the same or different for this site?

Comment: Do you have a question about a specific legend in mind?

Comment: @Yannis Most of my questions will more than not be dealing with Christian/biblical legends such as: Where is the popular belief that the gates of hell were located?

Comment: I would consider that to be on topic.

Comment: Given that there are already several questions here about legends, they must be on topic.

Comment: If they are on topic, I wonder if it would be worth it to rename the site "Mythology & Legends" or "Myths & Legends", since that would give a broader scope that would help keep the site alive.

Comment: @Thunderforge You should put in a proposal here: http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-we-rename-the-site-to-mythology-folklore-studies